# How to return all capital letters within string in Panda using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling to get the second output which is "None" when I tried to return all capital letters within the statement below

i tired the below

```
def findUpperCase(string):
    r = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', string)
    for word in string:
        if r == string:
            r
        return sorted(r)

print( findUpperCase('Hello World Paython.') )
# Output [Hello, World, Paython] 
print( findUpperCase('i am still learning') )
# Output None
```

Comment: Is your intent to only return a sorted list of capital letters? (`['H', 'P', 'W']`) Or are you returning a list of all words that start with a capital letter?

Comment: What about `I am still learning`?`

Comment: I want to return the below outputs: 1 output to be [Hello, World, Paython]  which already printed based on my code and i am struggling on how i can get the second output which should be as None

Comment: `\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b` would work. https://regex101.com/r/q9S9xd/1/

Comment: Second output is none, as regex doesn't match anything

Comment: The second output is none, as regex doesn't match anything: Yes this is what i want to print out as result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an empty list will evaluate as `False`, you can use an if statement and explicitly return `None` if the list is empty (no matches).

```
def findUpperCase(string):
    r = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', string)
    if r:
        return sorted(r)
    return None

print( findUpperCase('Hello World Paython.') )
# Output ['Hello', 'Paython', 'World'] 
print( findUpperCase('i am still learning') )
# Output None
```

Comment: This will fail for `I am still learning` and `Hey tHere bud`

Comment: Agreed. The regex can be tweaked based on users specific requirements. Unclear from the question and example. Seems like the main point was returning `None`

Comment: OP's code `for word in string:` has various telltale implications.

Comment: Yeah, needs clarification. A little ambiguous

Comment: Feel free to use the regex I commented earlier which fully solves OP's given task: `\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b`